# Javascript doesn't work with twitter bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I was trying to implement some javascript with twitter bootstrap's modal which works fine on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/baptme/WrrM3/) but doesn't work on my site.

HTML:

```
<a href="#Modal1" class="link-glow" data-toggle="modal">link</a>

<div class="modal fade" id="Modal1" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                 <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body" id="modalBody"></div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$('#Modal1').on('show', function () {
    $('#modalBody').html('<iframe width="560" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/8LCiz7OpfnQ?list=PLVL8S3lUHf0SxTfeIL55AGkEAd2zVPPbl" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>');
}).on('hide', function () {
    $('#modalBody').html('');
});
```

Could anyone please help me figure out what the problem is? Many thanks!

Comment: Did you include the bootstrap.js on your page?

Comment: check for errors thrown in browser console

Comment: Do you see any errors in the console? and you included jquery before including bs right?

Comment: Don't see any error in console, and I'm using rails bootstrap-sass, so it should be included.

Comment: on which browser/version is the problem occurring? what version of bootstrap are you using?

Comment: Please import bootstrap.css and bootstrap.js it will work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the Bootstrap docs, the events you want to use are `show.bs.modal` and `hide.bs.modal`.

See http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-usage

So your code would be:

```
$('#Modal1').on('show.bs.modal', function(event) {...}).on('hide.bs.modal', function(event) {...})
```